# Provider hosted app with windows authentication for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, windows-authentication, credentials

I have created a provider hosted app for SharePoint Online and deployed in Windows 2008 server with Windows authentication (clients requirement).

As I added the app to a SharePoint Online page it asks for Windows credentials, which is correct, but the client does not want to enter credentials again after having already logged in to SharePoint Online.

How can we authenticate the provider hosted app with SharePoint Online credentials?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

How do you create the provider hosted app for SharePoint Online?

Per my knowledge, Office 365 accepts only Low Trust Apps alone.

If you create the provider hosted app by Azure and Visual Studio, and you want to add the app into SharePoint Online, you need to package the app and then go to SharePoint admin center > apps > App Catalog > Apps for SharePoint library and upload the app file into this library.

After you trust The App in the SharePoint Online site, you can add the app in your site directly. Below article provide more information about how to add a provider hosted app into SharePoint Online, which may be helpful to you:

http://sharepointpals.com/post/Step-by-Step-Procedure-to-Create-a-Low-Trust-Provider-Hosted-App-for-Office-365-and-Host-the-AppWeb-in-Azure-WebSite